# How to reset a variable back to its full value?

Tags: processing, modulo

How would I go about reseting the y back to the full value? The modulo operator works on the x because the variable starts at 0 and it increases all the way to width, but I cannot figure out what to write y as to reset it back to full value.I cannot use more than the 2 declared variables.Thank you for help.

```java
int y=height;
int x=0;

void setup()
{
    size(100,100);
    frameRate(30);
}

void draw()
{
    background(200);
    line(0,y,width,y); //bottom to top
    line(0,x,width,x); // top to bottom
    line(y,0,y,height); //left to right
    line(x,0,x,height); //right to left
    y=y-1;
    x = (x+1) % width;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please specify

Comment: It's Processing, i tagged it as Processing, didn't know i can do more to specify sorry.

Comment: Ah OK! No problem then, Looks C++ , that's the reason I asked. Sorry :)

Comment: `y = (y-1) % height` might do the job, depending on how Processing defines modulo of a negative number.

Comment: i tried y = (y-1) % height before, it doesn't work :(, only x resets.

Comment: Why not the obvious `if ... else` construct (or `: ?` if you want a 1-line expression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an `if` statement that resets the variable when it reaches a certain value. Something like this:

```java
y = y - 1;
if(y < 0){
  y = height;
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on animation in Processing, including this reset technique, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

Comment: it worked ! thank you, i thought i could get around doing it with a modulo operator and i didn't think of using an if but this works so it's the same.